# iOS indoor positioning app and WiFi signals

Tags: ios, location, wifi, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

I'd like to develop an indoor positioning system for iOS by using WiFi signals instead of `iBeacon`. I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/maps/) that the feature was recently introduced. It says:

> You can sign up to learn more about how you can work with Apple to enable indoor positioning at your venue. Provide us with some basic information about your venue to get started.

and it leads to [Apple Maps Connect](https://mapsconnect.apple.com/?returnTo=%2Findoor), where you provide some information regarding the venue you'd want to enable for indoor positioning. I sent the request some weeks ago and I have no response yet, since they say they have a large amount of requests and they are prioritizing according to several conditions.

However, I'm not sure if this request through `Apple Maps Connect` is just to get more information from Apple of how to develop an indoor positioning app, or it is because yo need to be granted their explicit permission to do that, or why. Has somebody already completed this process?

On the other hand, the only information dealing with indoor positioning, apart from `iBeacon` related, is this [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html).

To make sure: the WiFi-enabled indoor positioning is only available starting from iOS 8? Just developing it will be enough, or is it needed to request any kind of specific permission to enable an indoor positioning based app for WiFi signals?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I imagine the request is necessary because they will need to get information from your venue on the location of the various WiFi Access Points as well as artwork for the internal map

Comment: @Paulw11 So... is there a different way to implement indoor positioning based in WiFi signals apart from using `Core Location` and the standard location service? The sample code I mentioned seems to do this by directly using the standard service. Is it possible to only read WiFi signals and their strength?

Comment: @AppsDev, You find any way to implement iOS 8 indoor map integration so please provide step of implementation to help community.